# What does the word, “blond” in “Donald Trump gets more chesty. And more blond” meean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Maureen Dowd’s article in New York Times (August 22) under the title, “Donald Trump Struts in His Own Pageant” starts with the following lines;

> “SOME blondes have all the fun. As Hillary Clinton and Jeb Bush get
>   more testy, Donald Trump gets more chesty. **And more blond**.”
>   http://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/23/opinion/sunday/maureen-dowd-donald-trump-struts-in-his-own-pageant.html?action

COD (10th Ed.) simply defines ‘blond / blonde’ as (1).adj. fair or pale yellow, having fair hair and a light complexion. (2). Women with blonde hair.

OALD defines ‘blond / blonde’ as (1). adj. (of hair) pale gold in color. (2.) n.(of a person) having blond hair.

I can easily understand Mr.Trump's hair gets grayer (or whiter). But can 69-year old man go 'more blond'? Actually his hair looks whiter than before.

What does “Donald Trump gets more blond (or darker)” mean? Does it have special connotation more than COD and OALD's definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, Oishi-san, it just means he appears to be dyeing his hair (what's left of it) more and more blond. (Note the picture of Trump in the photo which shows an almost glowing golden mane.) The writer is poking fun at Trump's comb-over and his vanity.

Comment: And it nicely invokes the thought of "dumb blonde", without the writer having to actually use that politically incorrect epithet.

Comment: Note, too, that the quote kicks off with an allusion to Clairol's ["Is it true blondes have more fun?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPaofg8i0i0) (see 0:30) -- which is [still](http://www.ispot.tv/ad/7cBR/progressive-blondes-have-more-fun) producing spinoffs.

Comment: It's contempt.  End of comment.